# Handling more than one db server/different schema in the same server in a single application

Tags: database-connection

As part of one of the requirements in our project we need to connect to a DB based on input in the UI and then fetch the result accordingly. Now this db can be on different db server or in the same db server it can be a different schema.

We are looking to do it in the most efficient way. 
One of the ways we have figured out is having the db connection information (like db server, schema etc) in separate properties files. Based on the input from the UI, we pass the input to a db factory that will read the corresponding properties file and will return the corresponding db connection if it already exists, if it doesn't then it will create a new connection and will return it.
We are using spring; we use weblogic for application deployment.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to let the respective functions "know" where to look for the requested data. But that's a lot of work in advance.

If the schemes describe similar data (e.g. address data), think about merging the data or the implementation of an frontend/proxy. Both ways would delegate the "looking for data" to the DB-Server(s) which should be able to handle each request way faster and more efficient than any program-logic.